# Page already in JSON format, wget outputting invalid JSON

Tags: bash, wget

I am able to wget a URL which already has data in JSON format.  However when viewing the output file there is extra whitespace and newlines, which is causing issues when trying to decode the JSON.

If I just copy and paste the page contents directly from a browser to a .json file the format is perfectly fine.

How can I ensure that wget outputs the page in the exact format it is displayed in, which is json format?

Thanks in advance.

Edit, sorry I have to use some obfuscation due to privacy concerns, but the issue should still be illustrated.

Command used:

```
wget --load-cookies=/home/cookies.txt --header "Accept:application/json" "https://url.com/url/json?" -O output.json
```

Snippet of the output format, notice the multiple lines, I included those from vi just to illustrate.  The actual output does not include those line numbers:

```
  1 
  2     {
  3       "callback": ["callback"],
  4       "attributes": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"],
  5       "types": ["string", "date", "string", "string", "string", "number", "number", "number", "string", "string"],
  6       "records": [["1", "2013-04-03", "blabla", "um", "yes", 1, 0, 0, " 5h 0m", "-1m"], ["2", "2013-04-03", "blabla", "er", "no", 0, 1, 1, " 5h 0m", "-1m"],
```

Comment: It would be "interesting" to show **what's your command line looks like** ! And a sample output should be interesting too...

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Sorry for the incomplete question.  Hopefully my edit provides enough information.

Comment: Anybody know why it is outputting like that?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using `tr -d "[:space:]"` on the entire output and got the file into a format that works.